# How to check if a value exists in DynamoDB effectively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Assume I have a DynamoDB which stores 1 million tokens (token is a simple string).
We generate the tokens ourselves (no AWS Cognito, no JWT, no AWS KMS etc). 
Tokens are unique (no duplications).

Table looks like this:

| Key ID | Token Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | !@#$%^ |
| 2 | ^&*()! |
| 3 | !#%&() |

I want to write a Lambda function that checks if a specific token exists in DB.
If exits in DB, returns TRUE.
If does not exist, returns FALSE.

However, the token is not the primary key,
so searching a token in this table means 
the database will need to check each record, ONE by ONE, 
to find if the token exists in DB or not,
which is very resource and time-consuming.

1. If I turn the "token value" column into a Global Secondary Index, 
   can DynamoDB check if the token exists by going directly to that KEY 
   instead of searching each record one by one? 
   ?
2. Which DynamoDB function is used to check if key exists in DB? 
   Is it GetItem?
3. **Re-edited**
   Why do I need to create GSI from the first place? 
   Doing that means I need to hold an extra table...
   Can I just have original table with Primary Key as TOKEN VALUE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. you can use GSI with primary key of your token.
2. Yes, `GetItem` will do the job.
3. Not sure what do you mean here. But I don't think there is any function in DynamoDB to search for substrings. You have to get the records first, and filter them on the client side.

Comment: Hi Marcin. Thanks for your reply. (1) Thanks. (2) So "GetItem" will confirm if key exists in a DB with millions of records in a split of a second, correct? (3) I re-edited the question: Why do I need to create a GSI from the first place...Having to create GSI means I need to hold a second table. Can I have the original table with token as primary key?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Keep in mind that you cannot add unicity constraint on secondary indexes
2. When using primary key (hash + potentially range key), you can use GetItem. Otherwise, you have to use Query command on table or indexes (you can use contains operator for string  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html)

For the third part, do you need unicity? You can create a secondary table which reverse value-key with the primary key on the token value. When adding a new token, you add the token + id to both table (with transaction?). It costs more on write.

You can also design a **single table** with different item types:

- pk: id#{id}, token
- pk: token#{token}, id

| pk | id | token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id#{id} | id | token |
| token#{token} | id | token |

This way, you can use `GetItem` directly when looking by id or token.

You can find more examples here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html

Comment: Hi. (1) I dont need to add unicity constraint because tokens are already unique. (2) By using GSI, I dont need "hash", don`t need "range key", I just want Primary Key to be the TOKEN value so I can search if a specific token exist in DB without searching the whole DB using "query" or "scan".  (3) I re-edit my question. Creating a GSI means I hold an extra table. Can I have the original table with token value sering as PRIMARY KEY...?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You cannot have, with a single row/item, 2 primary keys. You can do so by adding 2 items with 2 different pk representing the same data. It adds a little effort (and cost) on write. To ensure atomicity, you can use dynamodb transaction (more expansive).